# Match operator not picking up value in file

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a file with a list of servers (pinglist.ini) and a lookup (test1.txt) which contains a couple of servers, I am trying to match the servers in the test1.txt with the servers in pinglist, however if one server has a ; in front of it I want to terminate the script. At the moment I do have a server with a ; in front of the server name but the script only seems to be going to the else statement for all servers. I think I may have the parameters after my match operator incorrect

```
    $Check_File = gc 'C:\Jobs\Powershell\Pinger\PingList.ini'

    #Check Servers Not Already Marked Out

    Foreach ($_ in gc c:\jobs\logs\test1.txt)
    {
      If ($Check_File -match ";" + $_ ) 
      {
        Write-Host "Server $_ already marked out - Terminating"
        Exit 1
      }
      Else
      {
        Write-Host "Server $_ Not markedout - Carrying on"        
      }
   }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of PingList.ini and test1.txt.

Comment: pinglist.ini looks some like

Comment: pinglist.ini holds a large list of servers. ie 43=TSABCPRDS01, 44=DRABCW511, ;45=DRABCW512, etc. test1.txt holds a small list of servers to check if the semi-clon is present, ie. 44=DRABCW511, 45=DRABCW512, etc

Comment: damn that white space, my 
gc c:\jobs\logs\test.txt | where {$_ -ne ""} > c:\jobs\logs\test1.txt 
didn't clear it